# File upload not works in spring mvc and tomcat6

Tags: java, spring-mvc, file-upload, tomcat6, tomcat8

I am working in spring mvc with tomcat6. I tried to upload a file and able to do with war deployment using tomcat8.

But I am getting the following error, while using the same war with tomcat6 deployment.

```
    org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'userId' is not present
```

My complete code as follows,

Added jars in pom

```
    <!-- Apache Commons Upload -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache Commons Upload -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Added bean for upload in ApplicationContext.xml

```
    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000" />
    </bean>
```

Controller which return the userId

```
public class UploadDocController extends AbstractController {
@Resource
private UserService userService;


@Override
protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    Long userId = userService.getLoggedInUser(request).getId();

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView(UploadDocView.uploadmain);
    modelAndView.addObject("userId", userId);
    return modelAndView;
}
```

}

JSP:

```
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.htm">
        File to upload: 
        <input type="file" name="file"><br /> 

        <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="${userId}"><br /> <br />

        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>
```

FileUploadController.java

```
    @Controller
    public class FileUploadController {

    @Resource
    private CollectionsRepository collectionsRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public @ResponseBody String provideUploadInfo() {
            return "You can upload a file by posting to this same URL.";
        }

        @RequestMapping(value="/upload.htm", method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public ModelAndView handleFileUpload(@RequestParam(value ="userId") String userId, 
                @RequestParam(value ="file") MultipartFile file){
            System.out.println("userId--------"+userId);
            if (!file.isEmpty()) {
                try {
                    String filePath = "/home/ubuntu/analyzer/LOS/";
                    byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
                    File newFile = new File(filePath+""+file.getOriginalFilename());
                    BufferedOutputStream stream =
                            new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(newFile));
                    stream.write(bytes);
                    stream.close();

                    List<BankStatementError> errorList = new ArrayList<BankStatementError>();

                    Excelsheetreader esr = new Excelsheetreader();
                    List<String> listaddSN = esr.GetCalculation(Long.parseLong(userId), filePath+""+file.getOriginalFilename());

                    newFile.delete();

                    for (int i = 0; i < listaddSN.size(); i++) {
                        String bank = listaddSN.get(i);
                        BankStatementError error = collectionsRepository.getErrorByBank(bank);
                        errorList.add(error);
                    }

                    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView(UploadDocView.uploadsuccess);
                    modelAndView.addObject("errorList", errorList);
                    return modelAndView;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView(UploadDocView.uploadexecption);
                    return modelAndView;
                }
            } else {
                ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView(UploadDocView.uploadempty);
                return modelAndView;
            }
        }
    }
```

The error I am getting is

```
    org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'userId' is not present
```

Is there any other way to do this using tomcat6? hope someone will suggest in this.

Thanks in advance..

screenshot..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the time when you are calling your jsp file the parameter is not been attached with you response.

see-

```
<input type="hidden" name="userId" value="${userId}"><br /> <br />
```

here you are trying to access the value of **userId** but there might not be availability of the parameter you are looking for.

so possibly adding the parameter with the response will remove the error.

Comment: But the userId is available in the page, while I inspect element in browser.

Comment: Is thr ant solutions in this?

Comment: every thing looks fine @Mary.Hansen